# How to categorical data processing in Tensorflow 2.0 without hard-coded values?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Doing a bit of experiment with Tensorflow 2.0 and don't find how to deal with categorical data without hard-coding all possible values.

I'm following the documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/load_data/csv#categorical_data.

Here they hard-coded all possible values of their categorical data. What if I have a lot of values in there?

```
CATEGORIES = {
    'sex': ['male', 'female'],
    'class' : ['First', 'Second', 'Third'],
    'deck' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
    'embark_town' : ['Cherbourg', 'Southhampton', 'Queenstown'],
    'alone' : ['y', 'n']
}

def process_categorical_data(data, categories):
  """Returns a one-hot encoded tensor representing categorical values."""

  # Remove leading ' '.
  data = tf.strings.regex_replace(data, '^ ', '')
  # Remove trailing '.'.
  data = tf.strings.regex_replace(data, r'\.$', '')

  # ONE HOT ENCODE
  # Reshape data from 1d (a list) to a 2d (a list of one-element lists)
  data = tf.reshape(data, [-1, 1])
  # For each element, create a new list of boolean values the length of categories,
  # where the truth value is element == category label
  data = tf.equal(categories, data)
  # Cast booleans to floats.
  data = tf.cast(data, tf.float32)

  # The entire encoding can fit on one line:
  # data = tf.cast(tf.equal(categories, tf.reshape(data, [-1, 1])), tf.float32)
  return data
```

Another possibility is to do all the data processing in pandas (but what about big data?) which might be best suited for this kind of work.

Regards